# What is the meaning of the following PHP Code

Tags: php, wordpress, function

```
if ( !function_exists('solid_home_page_menu_args') ) {

function solid_home_page_menu_args(   ) {
    $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'solid_home_page_menu_args' );

}
```

I'm trying to figure out what the developer of this wordpress theme was thinking. Please assist. I'll be thankful.

So far I have understood most of the code in the functions.php file apart from the above code.

Comment: It's testing to see if a [function exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) before [adding it as a filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter). If it doesn't exist, the function is then defined before adding it as a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ( !function_exists('function_name') )` is used as a wrapper for functions used in a parent theme where `function_name` is the name of the function being wrapped by the conditional statement.

### WHAT THIS MEANS

- Whenever a parent theme author wraps a function in his theme in this conditional statement, it means the following for a child theme author

  - The child theme author can simply copy the function to the child theme and add/remove functionality within the function as he likes.
  - The child theme author don't need to change the function name, the same function name can be used. This is the **only** time where you can have two functions with the same name
  - The child theme author don't have to change any other template files to change calls to a new function

### HOW IT WORKS

The child theme's functions.php is loaded before the parent theme's functions.php. This means, if you have copied the function `function_name` to your child theme and modified it, it will be declared first before the function `function_name` in the parent theme.

Now, right before the function is declared in the parent theme, the conditional statement will first check if a function by the same name `function_name` already exists. If it does, then the function is skipped/ignored in the parent theme. If a function with that name is not found, then the function of the parent theme is declared and used

### TO CONCLUDE

If you are a parent theme author, it is really good practice to wrap your functions in this `if ( !function_exists('function_name') )` conditional statement. This will make live easier for child theme authors to modify or remove functions from your parent theme

**EDIT**

What is the meaning of this?

```
$args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
```

You will need to look at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1139) for the `wp_page_menu_args` filter inside the function `wp_page_menu`.

```
1146    if ( ! empty($args['show_home']) ) {
1147            if ( true === $args['show_home'] || '1' === $args['show_home'] || 1 === $args['show_home'] )
1148                    $text = __('Home');
1149            else
1150                    $text = $args['show_home'];
1151            $class = '';
1152            if ( is_front_page() && !is_paged() )
1153                    $class = 'class="current_page_item"';
1154            $menu .= '<li ' . $class . '><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . $args['link_before'] . $text . $args['link_after'] . '</a></li>';
1155            // If the front page is a page, add it to the exclude list
1156            if (get_option('show_on_front') == 'page') {
1157                    if ( !empty( $list_args['exclude'] ) ) {
1158                            $list_args['exclude'] .= ',';
1159                    } else {
1160                            $list_args['exclude'] = '';
1161                    }
1162                    $list_args['exclude'] .= get_option('page_on_front');
1163            }
1164    }
```

This hook allows you to set a key/value pair for the variable `$args` with a specific key `show_home` and the value a boolean of `true` which will allow you to display the `Home` link in the navigation bar

The `Home` link does not show by default in the navigation bar as this key/value pair does not exist. As soon as you set this key/value pair via the filter, then the conditional statement returns true and displays the `Home` link

Comment: Thanks alot @Pieter Goosen! what is the meaning of:    `$args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;`

Answer (score 1):

If the `solid_home_page_menu_args` function doesn't exist, it declares it and add it as a [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).